# Is the set of all functions from $\{1, ... ,n\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As listed above.  The most I can think of is that the cardinality of $\{1, ... ,n\}$ is n, but when it comes to sets of functions I am clueless.

Comment: It actually is countable, in general, if you have a finite set $\{1,...,n\}$ the cardinality of the set of all functions from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $\Bbb{N}$ is the cardinality of $\Bbb{N}^n$ which is exactly the same as that of $\Bbb{N}$ However I don't post it as an answer, because it implies some results which I don't know if you have already proven.

Comment: I'm given a theorem that states something to that effect.  Would simply using that theorem constitute a proof?  A large part of my struggle is knowing when I have a completed proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: note that specifying a function $f$ from $\{1, \ldots, n\} \to \mathbb{N}$ is the same as choosing an ordered $n$-tuple of elements of $\mathbb{N}$, where the first element of the tuple is $f(1)$, the second is $f(2)$, etc. Is the set of all such tuples countable? Post if you need a further hint.

Comment: So it's a countably infinite union of finite sets?

Comment: Why isn't the set finite?  It seems like there are only _**n**_ elements in each tuple, but an infinite number of tuples.

Comment: @Claycrusher: yes, but you're not counting based on the number of elements in the tuple. My comments above were mistaken though; it is a countable union of countable sets, not a finite union of countable sets. Do you have a copy of Rudin's ''Principles of Mathematical Analysis''? Theorem 2.13 may make things clearer. If not, I can summarize the argument.

Comment: I do have a copy, but I think it's an old edition (1953) and there is no Theorem 2.13.  Theorem 2.14 states that a sequence of countable sets is countable; is that the one you're referring to?

Comment: That's the one. It should be a proof by induction, and nicely summarizes what is happening here.

Comment: Ok.  Thank you for your help.  The only thing I am still unclear on is why each set is countable instead of finite.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(n)$ be the set of all functions from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $N$.   Let $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$ be a set of $n$ distinct prime numbers.For each function $f:\{1,...,n\}\to N $ let $$\pi (f)=\prod_{j=1}^{j=n}p_j^{f(j)} .$$ The function $\pi$ is 1-to-1.  For functions $f,g$ from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $N$, let $$f<^*g \text{ iff }\pi (f)<\pi (g).$$ For $g:\{1,...,n\}\to N$, let $$\psi (g)=k\in N$$  iff the set $\{f: f<^*g\}$ has exactly $k-1$ members. Now $\psi$ is a bijection from $F(n)$ to $N$.